# How do you get the Maiamai off the tops without using the Pegasus boots

Tags: zelda-link-between-worlds

How do you get the little maiamai off the tops of trees without using the pegasus boots cause my L button does not work

Comment: Interesting question. Now I want to know too :D

Answer (score 3):

#### Short answer:

You can't.

#### Long answer:

You can't. If your L button doesn't work, I recommend you have it repaired. Zelda won't be the only game that relies on a working L button.